# Im trying to add a button so when i click it the code (game) starts from scratch

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Hangman Test</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <button type="button" id="startButton">Start Game</button>
        <!-- This is where the blank word will be displayed -->
        <div id="city-text"></div>
        <div id="wins-guesses">
            <h2 id="wins-num"></h2>
            <h2 id="guesses-num"></h2>
        </div>

        <div id="letters-guessed"></div>
       </div>
      <script src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>   
    var secretWord = [];
    var underScoreWord = [];
    var wins = 0;
    var guessesRemaining = 15;
    var alreadyGuessed = [];
    var wordLetter = false;

    //Assign HTML elements to variables
    var cityText = document.getElementById("city-text");
    var winsNum = document.getElementById("wins-num");
    var guessesNum = document.getElementById("guesses-num")
    var lettersGuessed = document.getElementById("letters-guessed")


    //Array of cities
    var city = ["PARIS", "WELLINGTON", "HANOI", "PERTH", "MARSEILLE", "LONDON", "OTTAWA", "ZURICH", "BOSTON", "TOKYO", "DETROIT", "LIVERPOOL"];

    //console.log(city);
    //Pick random word from the team array and push the result to an empty array. 
    function pickRandomCity() {
        var randomCity = city[Math.floor(Math.random() * city.length)];
        secretWord = randomCity.split('');
        return randomCity;
    }

    var cityPicked = pickRandomCity();
    //Get length of secretWord and push as underscores to am empty array
    for (var i = 0; i < cityPicked.length; i++) {
        underScoreWord.push("_");

    }

    console.log('secretWord : ' + secretWord);
    // console.log('underScoreWord : ' + underScoreWord);
    // console.log('------------------');
    // console.log('cityPicked : ' + cityPicked);



    //Check for letters
    //Listen for key press and check to see if its a match
    var guessedLetters = {};
    document.onkeyup = function letterCheck(event) {
        var userGuess = event.key;
        if (!guessedLetters[userGuess.toUpperCase()]) { // check if user pressed this key
            alreadyGuessed.push(userGuess.toUpperCase());
            guessedLetters[userGuess.toUpperCase()] = true;
            guessesRemaining--;

        } else { // this key has been pressed before, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        secretWord.map((n, i) => {
            if (userGuess.toUpperCase() === n.toUpperCase()) {
                underScoreWord[i] = n;
            }
        })

        console.log("Already guessed: " + alreadyGuessed);
        lettersGuessed.textContent = ("Letters already guessed: " + alreadyGuessed);
        // Write to page
        cityText.textContent = underScoreWord.join(" ");
        winsNum.textContent = ("Wins: " + wins);
        guessesNum.textContent = ("Guesses Remaining: " + guessesRemaining);
        console.log(underScoreWord);

        //    Change counter
        if (guessesRemaining === 0) {
            cityText.textContent = ("You lose");
        }

        if (secretWord.toString() === underScoreWord.toString()) {
            cityText.textContent = ("You win");
            wins++;
        }

    }
    console.log(underScoreWord);
```

I'm trying to add a **button**. So, when I click it, the game starts from scratch -  All numbers refresh and the hidden word is ready to be guessed.  I have made it so when the full word has been guessed. It adds **wins++** and if the number of guesses goes to **zero** the there is a message that says **"You lose"**.

I'm trying to get it all connected so I can **press the button** anytime to start the game again.
 **How to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a simple solution that is to wrap everything you have in a function, and call that function when you click that button. Also disable the button when you run it, and enable it when game ends. Also clear the texts.
Another solution would be to just reset every variable and text.

```js
var wins = 0;
function newGame(){
  document.querySelector("#startButton").disabled = true;
  var secretWord = [];
  var underScoreWord = [];
  var guessesRemaining = 15;
  var alreadyGuessed = [];
  var wordLetter = false;

  //Assign HTML elements to variables
  var cityText = document.getElementById("city-text");
  var winsNum = document.getElementById("wins-num");
  var guessesNum = document.getElementById("guesses-num");
  var lettersGuessed = document.getElementById("letters-guessed");
  lettersGuessed.textContent = ("Letters already guessed: " + alreadyGuessed);
  guessesNum.textContent = ("Guesses Remaining: " + guessesRemaining);

  //Array of cities
  var city = ["PARIS", "WELLINGTON", "HANOI", "PERTH", "MARSEILLE", "LONDON", "OTTAWA", "ZURICH", "BOSTON", "TOKYO", "DETROIT", "LIVERPOOL"];

  //console.log(city);

  //Pick random word from the team array and push the result to an empty array. 
  function pickRandomCity() {
    var randomCity = city[Math.floor(Math.random() * city.length)];
    secretWord = randomCity.split('');
    return randomCity;
  }

  var cityPicked = pickRandomCity();

  //Get length of secretWord and push as underscores to am empty array
  for (var i = 0; i < cityPicked.length; i++) {
    underScoreWord.push("_");

  }
  cityText.textContent = underScoreWord.join(" ");
  console.log('secretWord : ' + secretWord);
  // console.log('underScoreWord : ' + underScoreWord);
  // console.log('------------------');
  // console.log('cityPicked : ' + cityPicked);



  //Check for letters
  //Listen for key press and check to see if its a match
  var guessedLetters = {};
  document.onkeyup = function letterCheck(event) {
    var userGuess = event.key;
    if (!guessedLetters[userGuess.toUpperCase()]) { // check if user pressed this key
      alreadyGuessed.push(userGuess.toUpperCase());
      guessedLetters[userGuess.toUpperCase()] = true;
      guessesRemaining--;

    } else { // this key has been pressed before, dont do anything
      return;
    }
    secretWord.map((n, i) => {
      if (userGuess.toUpperCase() === n.toUpperCase()) {
        underScoreWord[i] = n;
      }
    })

    console.log("Already guessed: " + alreadyGuessed);
    lettersGuessed.textContent = ("Letters already guessed: " + alreadyGuessed);
    // Write to page
    cityText.textContent = underScoreWord.join(" ");
    guessesNum.textContent = ("Guesses Remaining: " + guessesRemaining);
    console.log(underScoreWord);
    //    Change counter
    if (guessesRemaining === 0) {
      cityText.textContent = ("You lose");
      document.querySelector("#startButton").disabled = false;
    }
    if (secretWord.toString() === underScoreWord.toString()) {
      cityText.textContent = ("You win");
      wins++;
      winsNum.textContent = ("Wins: " + wins);
      document.querySelector("#startButton").disabled = false;
    }
  }
  console.log(underScoreWord);
}
newGame();
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <button type="button" id="startButton" onclick="newGame()">Start Game</button>
  <!-- This is where the blank word will be displayed -->
  <div id="city-text"></div>
  <div id="wins-guesses">
    <h2 id="wins-num"></h2>
    <h2 id="guesses-num"></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="letters-guessed"></div>
</div>
```